# database design to count distinct values

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-design, database-normalization

I want to keep track of different aspects in my application. These aspects are reported by the client to the server. The client reports data in the following format:

```
AspectReport
  ClientId int, //client that reported the apsect
  AspectId int, //aspect that we got a value for
  Value string  //arbitrary string
```

The same aspect can be reported several times with the same or different value.

At server side I only want to keep track of unqiue values per client and aspect. Thus I need to be able to store which values have been reported, and from which client.

A normalized structure would probably look like:

```
Aspect
  Id
  Name

// used to store all reported values for 
// the aspect, no matter which client reported it
// (each client can report a subset of all values)
ApplicationAspectValues   
  Id
  AspectId 
  Value

// Which unique values a specific client reported
ClientAspectValues
  Id
  ClientId
  AspectId
  Value
```

There can be thousands of clients (our largest customer have 20 000 clients to date) that can report thousands of values per aspect for a handful of aspects.

Writes are a lot more frequent that reads. I expect a couple of hundred reported aspects per second in the long run. Reads are used at most a couple of times per day (for a client).

The aspect values will rarely be used. Only to show the reported values when  analyzing the system deeper (a web app). Instead, the values are typically used to calculate the percentage of values reported for each aspect and client (`ClientValues.Count / ApplicationValues.Count`) and to make sure that only unique values are stored .

Following 3NF would mean that several rows are both queried and updated each time a new aspect is received which seems a bit inefficient.

Are there a better design that allows:

- Optimized writes
- Making sure that only unique values are stored
- Allows all values for a client/aspect to be occasionally retrieved (to be displayed to the user).

My naive implementation is to do the duplicate check in code and then store a gzipped comma separated string with all values in a column in `ApplicationAspectValues` and `ClientAspectValues` along with a Counter field.

Like this:

```
ClientAspectValues
  Id
  ClientId
  AspectId
  NumberOfUniqueValues
  Values
```

In that way there is only one row used to check for duplicates and to update reported values. And for most read scenarios the values are never fetched.

I'm certain that there are much better solutions?

*This question is posted here since a solution combining code and db is perfectly fine*

*(we have several other features in our product that write to the DB at the same frequency, the optimization isn't just to accommodate this feature but for the complete picture)*

Comment: If you want only unique values then make the value a primary key.  The database will not allow duplicates.

Comment: another option, store the unique values in c# cache and check that cache for existence, then you only need to insert to the table if it's not in the cache and clear the cache whenever you insert a new aspect. should reduce the load on the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use your 3NF design, but use table ClientAspectValue to store *all* new writes.

Then, I'd create a batch that would regularly read ClientAspectValue , get the unique values, and store them into a dedicated table - ClientAspectUniqueValues.

Comment: This was actually a great solution. No queries are required at all when adding the inbound values. And a single query is enough to find new unique values (using left joins). I named the first table `InboundPartitionValues` for clarity and kept the other table names.

Answer (score 0):

Schema Design:

A normalized structure should look like:

```
Client
  Client_ID        Primary Key
  Other_Columns....


Aspect
  Aspect_Id        Primary Key
  Name


ApplicationAspectValues   
  AAV_Id           Primary Key
  Aspect_Id        Foreign Key       
  Value                         Unique Constraint on Aspect_Id &  Value


ClientAspectValues
  CAV_Id            Primary Key
  Client_Id         Foreign Key
  AAV_Id            Foreign Key
  Reported          Time Stamp
```

Now create a view on ClientAspectValues to calculate Distinct values on the fly, Do not store the distinct values anywhere, it will be a pain to keep them updated, actually somewhat impossible.

Don't worry about the number of rows being added, think about storing all the information that you may need going forward (especially Reported Timestamp).

Also discuss with business and ask for some sort of retention period say 6 Months or maybe a Year.

Purge old data on nightly basis (older than whatever the retention period is decided by the business) to some sort of Data warehouse for reporting purposes.